# Camera output is always cropped via Android Camera2/CameraX. How to show full view?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

My app shows preview of the camera and saves pics to files. Both the preview and the saved pics only show part of the what the camera can see. The image is clearly cropped/clipped. How do I configure image capture to show the entire field of view of the camera?

The target app is an embedded system using a USB cam, but the problem happens in the emulator when configured for webcam0 -- the web cam I have connected to may laptop via USB. So, it's a similar setup. And the problematic behavior occurs in both this test/emulator setup as well as my embedded production setup. So, I think the issue is android -- not my embedded system configuration.

I have tried using both Camera2 and CameraX and I get the same behavior.

In an effort to share here I did follow this guide to create a simple camera app: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started. I know it's not a small code example, but it's the best I could think of since I don't know what part of the code is relevant.

The resulting app has the problem -- at least for me it does. Here's a snap of the app. It shows 1/2 of me when I know the camera is centered on me.

[image]

Somewhat oddly but maybe there's a clue here, if I rotate the emulated device, I then see a fuller view of the camera:

[image]

This is not even the complete view. Here's a snap from webcamtest:

[image]

I added this to the activity in hopes it would force the view to show the full view:

```
    viewBinding.viewFinder.setScaleType(PreviewView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)
```

But it has no effect :(

My app is in Java, but the getting-started app is Kotlin. The problem happens in either language so I'm open to talk about the issue and solutions in either language. I'll translate to Java if need be.

Here's the activity code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding

    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

    private var videoCapture: VideoCapture<Recorder>? = null
    private var recording: Recording? = null

    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            requestPermissions()
        }

        // Set up the listeners for take photo and video capture buttons
        viewBinding.imageCaptureButton.setOnClickListener { takePhoto() }
        viewBinding.videoCaptureButton.setOnClickListener { captureVideo() }

        var scaleType = viewBinding.viewFinder.getScaleType();
        viewBinding.viewFinder.setScaleType(PreviewView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)
        scaleType = viewBinding.viewFinder.getScaleType();

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        // Create time stamped name and MediaStore entry.
        val name = SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US)
            .format(System.currentTimeMillis())
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/CameraX-Image")
            }
        }

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions
            .Builder(contentResolver,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                contentValues)
            .build()

        // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                }

                override fun
                        onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults){
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: ${output.savedUri}"
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, msg)
                }
            }
        )}

    private fun captureVideo() {}

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewBinding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }
            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)

            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        activityResultLauncher.launch(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXApp"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS =
            mutableListOf (
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            ).apply {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                }
            }.toTypedArray()
    }

    private val activityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions())
        { permissions ->
            // Handle Permission granted/rejected
            var permissionGranted = true
            permissions.entries.forEach {
                if (it.key in REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS && it.value == false)
                    permissionGranted = false
            }
            if (!permissionGranted) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext,
                    "Permission request denied",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                startCamera()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What's your device model? CameraX only works with CTS compatible devices. From your description, it might not be one.

Comment: It's a Diji SOM. I have been using camera2 so far. I don't have a requirement to use camerax. I can test it with the CTS.